# How to modify the Verilog code to avoid syntax error?

Tags: verilog, fpga

the function is: when h posedge come, start count clk, if count to 105, r set 0, if count to 517, r set to 1; if count over 600,do nothing;
h is a periodic singal;

```
  module make_counter(h, clk, P);
        input wire h;
        input wire clk;
        output wire P;
        reg r=1'b1;
        reg[9:0] n=0;

        always @(negedge clk)
              always @(posedge h)
              begin 
                  n=0;
              end

              begin
              if(n<600)
                    n=n+1'b1;

              if(n==106)
                    r<=1'b0;
              else if(n==517)
                    r<=1'b1;
              else 
                    ;
              end
        assign P=r;
    endmodule
```

Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at main.v(115) near text "always";  expecting ";"

Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at main.v(119) near text "begin";  expecting "endmodule"

---

[image]

---

zhe image is what i want. when flag1 start set n=0, and count clk;
  when count to flag2, set P=0; when count to red arrow, set P=1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy you have some sort of bad code,

- Don't use always block inside always block
- Make variable name meaning full i.e. `cnt` instead of `n`
- Use reset, and avoid value assignment at declaration

  ```
  module make_counter(h, clk, P);
  input wire h;
  input wire clk;
  output wire P;
  wire r;
  reg[9:0] n=0;


  always @ (posedge clk or posedge h)
  begin
    if(h & (n < 10'd600)) begin
      n <= n + 1'd1;
    end else begin
      n <= n;
    end
  end

  assign r = (n == 10'd105) ? 1'b0 : ( (n == 10'd517) ? 1'b1 : 1'bx );
  assign P = r;

  endmodule
  ```

You have not mentioned that, what should be the value of `r` if `n` is in between 0 to 104 and 106 to 516 and > 517?

I assumed it ll be anything.

Check it and say it works for you

Comment: i add a image to show my thought, zhe code is not reflect my thought

Comment: zhe cases:  n is in between 0 to 104 and 106 to 516 and > 517,  not need take care.

Comment: I m confused. Your thoughts are not clear. Please draw diagram and explain